# AdaBoost - Ensemble model perform poor than best weak classifier

Tags: machine-learning, classification, xgboost, ensemble-modeling, ensemble-learning

Can Adaboost's ensemble classifier perform worse than the best of the weak learners considered? If so when in what case of weak learner the ensemble learning does not perform better?

Comment: Do you have any practical exemple, or is this a theoretical question ?